# cancel current request on new request jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

i have a jqgrid, the grid gets the data on json format from my server.

the grid have some blanck cells and the user can doubleclick them, then an ajax req is send so the server updates a value (current date) and reload the grid, the problem im having is that if i click to fast on 2 or more cells, only the reload for the first cell hapends, if i refresh my page all my data is loaded so i know all request where send ok but apears that the grid reload, can not execute a a new request until the lastone has finished, any idea onn how to solve it?

w i ended up doing:
create a var like:

```
var lastRequestXHR;
```

on my jqgrid code i add:

```
    loadBeforeSend: function (xhr) {
        lastRequestXHR = xhr;
    },
```

and my reload function:

```
function refreshGrid() {
    if (lastRequestXHR != null) {
        lastRequestXHR.abort();
    }
    jQuery('#scheduledGrid').trigger('reloadGrid');
}
```

Comment: You can use the `abort()` function.

Comment: Would it not be confusing to your users if you are aborting their input without some feedback?  Would it not be better to display some sort of "working" spinner image (especially if lag is introduced) and disable subsequent updates until the first one has either been performed or errored out.

Comment: not on this specific case, because those actions end up on the reload of the grid, and i need the result of the last only, if they old request ar aborted (as just finish doing) the server will still perform the database changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just push each ajax request to any variable, and in success function abort all request.
Some code like below what I intend:

```
 requests.push(
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '<any url>',
            data: ResponseData,
            success: function(data) {
               for(var i = 0; i < requests.length; i++)
                  requests[i].abort();
            }
        }));
```

Please note this will cancel all request & its handler on client-side & server request sent will execute but client will not wait for response.

Comment: i ended up doing somthing similar, i store my resquest action on a var     `loadBeforeSend: function (xhr) {
                lastRequestXHR = xhr;
            }` then on my refresh function aborted it before call the grid reload `lastRequestXHR.abort();`, tks